# Stop .animate() when it reaches last div

Tags: jquery, web-applications, jquery-mobile, jquery-animate

So I have a web app where each panel is 480x300 (-20px for status bar) and two navigation buttons to scroll left or right.

Now everything works great, except when you continue scrolling past the max panels displayed, it keeps going.

I was wondering if it is possible to stop the Jquery .animate() after it reaches the last panel.

http://jsfiddle.net/gS33Y/

Comment: Can you not add a check into your clicks to only animate one way if the margin doesnt equal 0, and only the other way if the it doesnt equal the number of lis * however much you're animating each time?

Comment: Well I really want to thank everybody. I think though (stupidly, admittedly too) that for a 5 panel app i can just add the next and previous buttons on the panels necessary.

In the case of developing longer ones, I will definitely utilise them :]

Thankyou all. Man I feel like a rookie -.-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hiya **another demo** http://jsfiddle.net/qpHSw/ **or** http://jsfiddle.net/yEsDQ/ **or** http://jsfiddle.net/yEsDQ/show

this sample dynamically counts your li in ul and adjust the animate according.

**code**

```
   var cur = 1;
var max = $(".scroll-content ul").children("li").length;

$("nav.back").click(function(){

    if (cur+1 > max) return;
    cur++;

    $("#panel").animate({
        marginLeft: "-=500px",
    }, 1000);

});

$("nav.forward").click(function(){
    if (cur-1 < 1) return;
    cur--; 
    $("#panel").animate({
        marginLeft: "+=500px",
    }, 1000);

});​
```

Comment: And Ill give it you for the easiest application!

Comment: Hiya @user1086990 glad it helped, :) cheers, I have removed alert in this one: http://jsfiddle.net/qpHSw/ just in case, have a good one, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict the x co-ordinate position to a certain a value if it is last panel.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a count to track the current display. Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/gS33Y/3/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `data-x` attributes on the `#panel` element to count the number of panels, and track which panel is displayed to limit the movement. Also, you should be incrementing the slide margin by 500px (460 width + 20px margin + 20px padding).

Try this:

```
var $panel = $("#panel")
$panel.data("slideCount", $("#panel li").length).data("currentSlide", 1);

$("nav.back").click(function() {
    if ($panel.data("currentSlide") < $panel.data("slideCount")) {
        $("#panel").animate({
            marginLeft: "-=500px",
        }, 1000);
        $panel.data().currentSlide++;
    }
});

$("nav.forward").click(function(){
    if ($panel.data("currentSlide") > 1) {
        $("#panel").animate({
            marginLeft: "+=500px",
        }, 1000);
        $panel.data().currentSlide--;
    }
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gS33Y/20/)

Answer (score 0):

Is there anyway to detect when the window width end is near and terminate the marginLeft at the end of slide 5 leaving no white space on the right?