# jQuery stop animate at the last div

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

What I'm trying to achieve is "stop" the animation when reaching the first/last div within a bigger div.

My setup: First I calculate the view to start at a certain div with the class 'closed' then I animate #all_fixtures left/right with nav buttons. This all works fine!

What I need is for the animation to stop when reaching the first/last **.fixture** div within the **#all_fixtures** wrapper div.

**jQuery**

```
// Find first div with the class '.closed' and start view there
$(function() {
$('#all_fixtures').css({marginLeft: -$('.closed').last().offset().left});
});

// Animate div left/right           
$('.scores_prev').click(function() {
$('#all_fixtures').animate({ 'left': '+=400px' }, 300 );
});
                
$('.scores_next').click(function() {
$('#all_fixtures').animate({ 'left': '-=400px' }, 300 );
});
```

**HTML**

```
   <div id="all_fixtures">
       <div class="fixture closed"> 4 </div>
       <div class="fixture closed"> 3 </div>
       <div class="fixture closed"> 2 </div>
       <div class="fixture closed"> 1 </div> <!-- start view here -->
       <div class="fixture"> 1 </div>
       <div class="fixture"> 2 </div>
    </div>
    <a class="scores_prev"> PREV </a>
    <a class="scores_next"> NEXT </a>
```

**Notes:**

- ## all_fixtures is 10000px
- .fixture are some 200px in width & floated right (Meaning that the #all_fixtures will have empty space to the left)

I've tried something along these lines, but I couldn't get it to work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10410528/1864622

///

Answer (score 0):

You can get first and the last div inside the **#all_fixtures** wrapper like this:

```
$("#all_fixtures div.fixture:first");
$("#all_fixtures div.fixture:last");
```

Once you get the div you can stop the animation by calling [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/). When .stop() is called on an element, the currently-running animation (if any) is immediately stopped. If, for instance, an element is being hidden with .slideUp() when .stop() is called, the element will now still be displayed, but will be a fraction of its previous height. Callback functions are not called.

Comment: tried implementing your code in every possible way, but no luck...will try some more.

Comment: Thanks @palash-mondal // here's a file over at our servers: http://borozani.com/jquery/test-slide.html // For some reason couldn't get jsfiddle to work the same as on the browser // Please, notice how the slide starts at the very last '.closed' div (everything is floated right)

Comment: Perfect! That's it / now if it stopped left/right at the very last divs (very last div to the right would be .fixture & very last div to the left would be .fixture_dates).

Comment: Here I've added few more divs ahead/back for the effect to have more visible impact: **UPDATED:** http://jsfiddle.net/QBDXQ/1/

Comment: Man thanks for the try / not yet though: Check out this updated version http://jsfiddle.net/QBDXQ/5/ (there are few divs below '.closed' class and now those are _un-navigatable_ // Also, the last div to the right should 'stick' to the right of the browser. Sorry am asking for too much, but I've searched and searched and no luck yet : /

Comment: Also, I don't think counting div's will work. Needs to be something that checks if it's the first/last div (or maybe .next()?!) // or even disabling left/right buttons on reaching the first/last div.